# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, UserNote>' in type cast?

Tags: flutter, dart

In order to make an HTTP request using Post method, I've created a method called AddNotes as shown below:

```
 Future<void> addNotes(UserNote userNote) async{
    String url = "dashboard/user_notes/";
     try {
         final response = await Api.Post(
           url: url, 
        body: json.encode({
                 'display_id': userNote.display_id,
                  'note': userNote.note,
                  'created_at': Tracker.encode(userNote.created_at!),
                   'updated_at': Tracker.encode(userNote.updated_at!),
          }) as Map<String, dynamic>
          );
            print(response.body);

          final newNote = UserNote(
            id: userNote.id,
            display_id: userNote.display_id,
             note: userNote.note,
             created_at: userNote.created_at,
             updated_at: userNote.updated_at);
             notesList.add(newNote);
                 notifyListeners();  
     } catch (e) {
        print("error loading notes");
        print(e.toString());
     }
 }
```

When I tried to print the response on the console, I got the following error :

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

Anyone have an idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `json.encode()`, the method will return a string with a json parsed.

Imagine your json like this:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar"
  "hello": 1
}
```

When you encode, your result will be a string like that:
`'{"foo":"bar","hello":1}'`

So, you don't need to use `as Map<String, dynamic>` in your body.

Comment: When I removed as Map<String, dynamic>, the full body of json.encode raised error!!

Comment: What if you try to send the body without the `json.encode`?

Answer (score 0):

If you check runtimeType of `json.encode()` it shows `String` type and you cannot cast it to `Map<String,dynamic>`.

```
var object = {
                 'display_id': userNote.display_id,
                 'note': userNote.note,
                 'created_at': Tracker.encode(userNote.created_at!),
                 'updated_at': Tracker.encode(userNote.updated_at!),
          };

var jEncode = json.encode(object);
// you can cast it directly
var map = object as Map<String,dynamic>;
// if you decode then cast to Map from encode result
var jToMap = json.decode(jEncode) as Map<String,dynamic>;

print(jEncode.runtimeType);
print(map.runtimeType);
print(jToMap.runtimeType);
```

results

```
String
_JsonMap
JsLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
```